# How to add checkboxes from database into Jquery UI Dialogue box

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-ui-dialog

I have button which onclick gets the value from database and stores into javascript variable.
Now i want to add this variable values into dialogue box as checkbox.here is my html code for dilaogue box ...

HTML for dialogue box.

```
<input type="submit" name ="Select Sites" id="ssites" value="Select Sites">
   <div id="sites" title="Choose Sites">
<form action="" method="POST" id="sites">
</form>
```

And here is my script code..

```
 var calltype;
   $('#ssites').click(function(evt){
     evt.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
     url: "Calltype",              
     type: "GET", 
     success: function(data){
     calltype=data;

     var cb = $('<input/>', {
    'type':'checkbox',
    'name':'sites_radio', // so you can access it on server using this name
    'value':calltype // assumed "data" contains the value
});
$("#sites").append($('<label/>', { 'text':'CheckBox Label' }).prepend(cb))
.dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        SUBMIT: function() {
            $(this).find('form').submit();
        }
    }
});
  },
  error:function(){
      console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
  }   
});
```

checkbox values from database are in sites variable...

please guys help me .I have no idea how to go further..

Any help will be highly apprecaited..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your `HTML` seems wrong, is that all you got ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all id should be unique.. so change your form id to

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form-sites">


$.ajax({
 ...
success: function(data){
 $.each(data,function(i,v){
    $('<input />',{
         'type':'checkbox',
         'name':'someName',
         'value':'someValue'
     }).appendTo('#form-sites');
 }); 
},
...
 jQuery("#sites").dialog({
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
     SUBMIT: function() {
         $('#form-sites').submit();
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: sir i edited my post with your code .Now so many checkboxes are coming and name of checkbox is also not coming ..whereas ther is only five values in variable calltype

Comment: can u show me your structure of data returned in success function

Comment: [LOCAL, STD, ISD, INCOMING, INET] this is the structure of the data returned in success function

Comment: is it in json ?? if not return this as json... you can change the name and value of input corresponding to the returned data.

Comment: i parsed the value returned into json by this code calltype=jQuery.parseJSON(data); but now its not showing checkbox also

Answer (score 0):

Your `HTML` is not right and question is a little confusing but to add a `checkbox` in your form with value received from `ajax` (in `success` callback) and make it (sites div) a `dilog` using `jQuery ui`, you may try ssomething like this in your `success` callback

```
success:function(data){
    var cb = $('<input/>', {
        'type':'checkbox',
        'name':'sites_radio', // so you can access it on server using this name
        'value':data // assumed "data" contains the value
    });
    $("#sites").append($('<label/>', { 'text':'CheckBox Label' }).prepend(cb))
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            SUBMIT: function() {
                $(this).find('form').submit();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[**An Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6XWw/1/)

**Update :** (it seems you have an `array` in your `data` (mentioned in comment)), so you should use something like this in your `success` callback ([**Updated Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6XWw/2/))

```
success:function(data){
    // assumed "data" contains following array
    // ['LOCAL', 'STD', 'ISD', 'INCOMING', 'INET'];
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        var cb = $('<input/>', {
            'type':'checkbox',
            'name':'sites_radio',
            'value':v
        });

        $("#sites").append($('<label/>', {
            'style':'display:block',
            'text':v
        }).prepend(cb))
    });

    $('#sites').dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            SUBMIT: function() {
                $(this).find('form').submit();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you sir for ur response now one checkbox is coming and that is CheckBox Label but i want to show checkboxes from the values got from ajax call..

Comment: Value is set using `'value':data`, I assumed that you have stored the value in `data` variable.

Comment: You said, you have the value in the variable in your `success`, so it suppose to be `data`, so what it is now ?

Comment: it is in varaible calltype=data; and calltype has following values formate [LOCAL, STD, ISD, INCOMING, INET].So i need to show these values as checkbox in dialogue box